# i get mistake TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: typescript

My class

```
class Sources {
  draw(data: object[]): void {
    const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    const sourceItemTemp = document.querySelector("#sourceItemTemp") as HTMLTemplateElement;

    data.forEach((item) => {

      const sourceClone = sourceItemTemp.content.cloneNode(true) as HTMLInputElement;
      const sourceItemName = sourceClone.querySelector(".source__item-name");
      const sourceItem = sourceClone.querySelector(".source__item");

      if (sourceItemName && sourceItem) {
        sourceItemName.textContent = item.name;
        sourceItem.setAttribute("data-source-id", item.id);
      }

      fragment.append(sourceClone);
    });

    const doc = document.querySelector(".sources");
    if (doc) {
      doc.append(fragment);
    }
  }
}
```

I get mistakes:

> TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'.
> TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'object'.

when i add type for **item**

```
    data.forEach((item: {
      name: string,
      id: string
    })
```

I get mistake

> TS2345: Argument of type '(item: {    name: string;    id: string;}) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: object, index: number, array: object[]) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'item' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ name: string; id: string; }': name, id

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAJVT.png)

item have view after request [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxagG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You define in the function head that data is an object array. Please add a proper type here. `draw(data: { id: string, name: string }[]): void { /* ... */ }`